# How do I draw a circle around a term in an align* equation?

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols, align, circles

Here's what my equation looks like; it's in an `align*` environment:

[image: equation]

I want to put a circle around `$\varepsilon \frac{dL}{d\varepsilon}$` and everything else unchanged.

> **Q**: How do I draw a circle around a term in an `align*` equation?

I found that `\textcircled` doesn't work in math mode and `\tikz \node[circle,draw] { $\varepsilon \frac{dL}{d\varepsilon}$};` is not suitable as it shifts the term:

[image]

I get fairly close using `\boxed{\varepsilon \frac{dL}{d\varepsilon}}`, but it's not a circle:

[image]

Here's a working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
L(q+\varepsilon) = L(q) + \varepsilon \frac{dL}{d\varepsilon} + \cdots \\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The TikZ-way you tried works, you just forgot to set the baseline of the `tikzpicture` to the baseline of the text inside the math node.  Here is an adjusted solution which also respects the mathstyle outside of the node.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% superior to amsmath
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mathcircled[1]{%
  \mathpalette\@mathcircled{#1}%
}
\newcommand\@mathcircled[2]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(math.base)] \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt] (math) {$\m@th#1#2$};%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  L(q+\varepsilon)
  &= L(q) + \mathcircled{\varepsilon \frac{dL}{d\varepsilon}} + \cdots \\
  &= \textstyle L(q) + \mathcircled{\varepsilon \frac{dL}{d\varepsilon}} + \cdots \\
  &= \scriptstyle L(q) + \mathcircled{\varepsilon \frac{dL}{d\varepsilon}} + \cdots \\
  &= \scriptscriptstyle L(q) + \mathcircled{\varepsilon \frac{dL}{d\varepsilon}} + \cdots
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks, that's exactly what I'm after.

Comment: What is the meaning of `$\m@th#1#2$`. Would you please explain the code.

Comment: @Misaki The definition is `\m@th: macro:->\mathsurround \z@`.  That is to say, it sets `\mathsurround` to `0pt`.

Comment: I am trying to add two circles instead of one, i used your code and add one in another `\mathcircled{\mathcircled{\varepsilon \frac{dL}{d\varepsilon}}}`, but the spacing between them is large besides i can't change the color of the other. would you please help. Thanks

Comment: @Misaki Instead of nesting, use this definition of `\dblmathcircled`: `\newcommand\dblmathcircled[1]{\mathpalette\@dblmathcircled{#1}} \newcommand\@dblmathcircled[2]{\tikz[baseline=(math.base)]\node[draw,circle,double,inner sep=1pt] (math) {$\m@th#1#2$};}`.

Comment: U defined tikz double error.

Comment: Very nice solution as far as I understand it! It would be helpful if you added how the macro, \mathpalette and tikz commands work. I was able to figure it out at a fairly high level using chatGPT.