# Symbol inside a circle in a table

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I need to have a sequence of lines, in which some symbols are circled. Right now I am using a table, the output is shown in the picture:

[image]

However as you can see the circles are overlapping with the border of the table, moreover the circles on SN are bigger than the one for S[0-9]. I would like to have an equal distance from the border and an equal circle size for every symbol. These should also include having the same dimension for each row.
The code I am using is for the circle the following:

```
\usepackage{mathtools}% superior to amsmath
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mathcircled[1]{%
    \mathpalette\@mathcircled{#1}%
}
\newcommand\@mathcircled[2]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(math.base)] \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt] (math) {$\m@th#1#2$};%
}
\makeatother
```

The code for the table:

```
\begin{center}
        \begin{table}[]
            \centering
            \label{my-label}
            \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
                \hline
                S1  & S1  & $\mathcircled{S1}$  & ... & S1  \\ \hline
                $\mathcircled{S2}$  & $\mathcircled{S2}$  & S2  & ... & S2  \\ \hline
                ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\ \hline
                SN  & $\mathcircled{SN}$  & $\mathcircled{SN}$  & ... & SN  \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
    \end{center}
```

I have taken the code from a previous question: [How do I draw a circle around a term in an align* equation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249688/how-do-i-draw-a-circle-around-a-term-in-an-align-equation)

Thank you.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mathtools}% superior to amsmath
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mathcircled[1]{%
    \mathpalette\@mathcircled{#1}%
}
\newcommand\@mathcircled[2]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(math.base)] \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt] (math) {$\m@th#1#2$};%
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]    %% this does it

\newcommand{\cmmnt}[1]{\ignorespaces}


\begin{document}

    \newpage


    \begin{center}
        \begin{table}[]
            \centering
            \label{my-label}
            \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
                \hline
                S1  & S1  & $\mathcircled{S1}$  & ... & S1  \\ \hline
                $\mathcircled{S2}$  & $\mathcircled{S2}$  & S2  & ... & S2  \\ \hline
                ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\ \hline
                SN  & $\mathcircled{SN}$  & $\mathcircled{SN}$  & ... & SN  \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
    \end{center}
```

Comment: can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Done it. @samcarter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a proposal. Note that you need to reorder `table` and `center`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}% superior to amsmath
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mathcircled[1]{%
    \mathpalette\@mathcircled{#1}%
}
\newcommand\@mathcircled[2]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(math.base),outer sep=auto]{\node[draw,circle,inner
    sep=1pt]
    (math) {$#1#2$};
    \path (math.north)--++(0,1pt);
    \path (math.south)--++(0,-1pt);}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
            \centering

            \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
                \hline
                S1  & S1  & $\mathcircled{S1}$  & ... & S1  \\ \hline
                $\mathcircled{S2}$  & $\mathcircled{S2}$  & S2  & ... & S2  \\ \hline
                ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\ \hline
                SN  & $\mathcircled{SN}$  & $\mathcircled{SN}$  & ... & SN  \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}
\caption{A table with circles.}\label{my-label}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**UPDATE**: Because you asked me to do that. @samcarter was faster anyway, but personally I'd not go that way.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}% superior to amsmath
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mathcircled[1]{%
    \mathpalette\@mathcircled{#1}%
}
\newcommand\@mathcircled[2]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(math.base),outer sep=auto]{\node[draw,circle,inner
    sep=1pt,minimum width=0.8cm]
    (math) {$#1#2$};
    \path (math.north)--++(0,1pt);
    \path (math.south)--++(0,-1pt);}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
            \centering

            \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
                \hline
                S1  & S1  & $\mathcircled{S1}$  & ... & S1  \\ \hline
                $\mathcircled{S2}$  & $\mathcircled{S2}$  & S2  & ... & S2  \\ \hline
                ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\ \hline
                SN  & $\mathcircled{SN}$  & $\mathcircled{SN}$  & ... & SN  \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}
\caption{A table with circles.}\label{my-label}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

And thanks @percusse, you're right, as always. ;-)

Comment: Thank you, however, I need also the circle to be of the same dimension.

Comment: @GuidoMuscioni Well, I can write something assuming that `$SN$` are the largest objects you will encircle. But is that really what you want? What if you encounter even larger object later?

Comment: Related : [when-should-we-use-begincenter-instead-of-centering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23650/)

Comment: I mean I would like to have all circles to have the same dimension, $SN$ is a simplification, I have also more complex symbols. @marmot

Comment: @GuidoMuscioni Without scanning twice you will not know what your widest element would be. You need to set a maximum width to have a one shot solution

Comment: @percusse Yet another point on which I agree with you. ;-)

Comment: @percusse Do you know why `outer sep` does not work here?

Comment: @GuidoMuscioni Thanks for accepting my answer, but consider accepting samcarter's, who was faster.

Comment: I have written why I do not consider his as a solution. @marmot

Comment: @GuidoMuscioni Please keep marmots answer as the accepted!

Comment: @GuidoMuscioni Please don't call me "his" :)

Comment: @marmot Outer sep is used when trying to find a point on the shape border. It doesn't actually pad a node. Test: `\begin{tikzpicture}\node[outer sep=10cm] (a) at (0,0) {Z};\draw (2,2) -- (a);\end{tikzpicture}` Remove and add the `\draw` command for different picture sizes.

Comment: @percusse Thanks!! Yes, I agree. I was just too naive when I thought it does the trick. (But I learned a new thing: `outer sep=auto` ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use the rules from `booktabs` which have some vertical padding around them:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\mathcircled[1]{%
    \mathpalette\@mathcircled{#1}%
}
\newcommand\@mathcircled[2]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(math.base)] \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt] (math) {$\m@th#1#2$};%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

        \begin{table}[]
            \centering
            \label{my-label}
            \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
                \toprule
                S1 & S1 & $\mathcircled{S1}$ & ... & S1 \\ \midrule
                $\mathcircled{S2}$ & $\mathcircled{S2}$ & S2 & ... & S2 \\ \midrule
                ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\ \midrule
                SN & $\mathcircled{SN}$ & $\mathcircled{SN}$ & ... & SN \\ \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To make the circles the same size, you can specify a `minimum size`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mathcircled[1]{%
    \mathpalette\@mathcircled{#1}%
}
\newcommand\@mathcircled[2]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(math.base)] \node[draw,circle,minimum size=30pt] (math) {$\m@th#1#2$};%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}


\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}
    \belowrulesep=1ex
    \aboverulesep=1ex
    \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
        \midrule
        S1  & S1  & $\mathcircled{S1}$  & $\dots$ & S1  \\ \midrule
        $\mathcircled{S2}$  & $\mathcircled{S2}$  & S2  & $\dots$ & S2  \\ \midrule
        $\dots$ & $\dots$ & $\dots$ & $\dots$ & $\dots$ \\ \midrule
        SN  & $\mathcircled{SN}$  & $\mathcircled{SN}$  & $\dots$ & SN  \\ \midrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, however this solution overlaps circle with the borders. @samcarter

Comment: @GuidoMuscioni They don't overlap, I adjusted the row height to make the circles touch the lines. You can choose another array stretch.