# How do I draw an optionally colored circle/square/ellipse around a symbol

Tags: tikz-pgf, optional-arguments, tikz-node

In [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249688/how-do-i-draw-a-circle-around-a-term-in-an-align-equation), @HenriMenke showed how to put a circle around a symbol.    It's easy to modify his code to color the circle, see below, but I don't understand how to make the color an optional argument, i.e., with default black, and a color as an additional optional argument.   This would be easy normally, but in this code, for some reason I don't understand the number of arguments passed to `\mathcircled` is different from the number passed to `\@mathcircled`

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mathcircled[1]{%
  \mathpalette\@mathcircled{#1}%
}
\newcommand\@mathcircled[2]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(math.base)] \node[draw,color=red,circle,inner sep=1pt] (math) {$\m@th#1#2$};%
}
\makeatother
```

Another question is how to change the shape of the surrounding object.   You'd think you could replace `circle` as the third argumnent of `\node` with `square` or `oval` or `ellipse` but none of these options work.
I've also tried things like `shape=ellipse` but that doesn't work either.
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: You can exchange `circle` with `ellipse`, but you have to `\usetikzlibrary{shapes}` in your preamble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could wrap the two arguments in one:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mathcircled[2][red]{%
  \mathpalette\@mathcircled{{#1}{#2}}%
}
\newcommand\@mathcircled[2]{%
  \@mathcircled@b{#1}#2%
}
\newcommand\@mathcircled@b[3]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(math.base)] \node[draw,color=#2,circle,inner sep=1pt] (math) {$\m@th#1#3$};%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\mathcircled[blue]{55}$
\end{document}
```

Without a second helper macro, you could as well put `\@mathcircled` and `{#1}` in one argument of `\mathpalette`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mathcircled[2][red]{%
  \mathpalette{\@mathcircled{#1}}{#2}%
}
\newcommand\@mathcircled[3]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(math.base)] \node[draw,color=#1,circle,inner sep=1pt] (math) {$\m@th#2#3$};%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\mathcircled[blue]{55}$
\end{document}
```

Both code blocks result in:

[image]

**Edit:** As requested a version taking more arguments (3 to be precise).

An approach taking two optional arguments in a row. If the first argument is empty it is set to `red` (which makes `red` the default, as it is empty by default). The second optional argument specifies the shape, defaulting to `circle`. I tried to explain the code a bit in comments:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mathcircled[1][]
  {%
    % keeping stuff local
    \begingroup
    % check whether #1 is empty
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
      % save red as the colour for later
      \def\mathcircled@color{red}%
    \else
      % save #1 as the colour for later
      \def\mathcircled@color{#1}%
    \fi
    % grab the next optional argument and the mandatory one
    \mathcircled@b
  }
\newcommand\mathcircled@b[2][circle]
  {%
    % expand the colour and read the expanded colour and the other two arguments
    \expandafter\mathcircled@c\expandafter{\mathcircled@color}{#1}{#2}%
  }
\newcommand\mathcircled@c[3]
  {%
    % putting the two optional arguments with \mathcircled@d into the first
    % argument of \mathpalette
    \mathpalette{\mathcircled@d{#1}{#2}}{#3}
    \endgroup
  }
\newcommand\mathcircled@d[4]
  {%
    \tikz[baseline=(math.base)]
      \node[draw,color=#1,#2,inner sep=1pt] (math) {$\m@th#3#4$};%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\mathcircled[blue]{55}$
$\mathcircled[][ellipse]{69}$
$\mathcircled{5}$
\end{document}
```

Results:

[image]

A version of the edit using `xparse`:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{xparse}
\makeatletter
% this will be used to parse the first optional argument of \mathcircled to
% set the default.
\newcommand \EmptyArgParse [2]
  {%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
      \def\ProcessedArgument{#1}%
    \else
      \def\ProcessedArgument{#2}%
    \fi
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \mathcircled { >{\EmptyArgParse{red}}O{} O{circle} m }
  {%
    \mathpalette{\mathcircled@b{#1}{#2}}{#3}%
  }
\newcommand\mathcircled@b[4]
  {%
    \tikz[baseline=(math.base)]
      \node[draw,color=#1,#2,inner sep=1pt] (math) {$\m@th#3#4$};%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\mathcircled[blue]{55}$
$\mathcircled[][ellipse]{69}$
$\mathcircled{5}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much @Skillmon.        I tried to generalize to `\newcommand\mathShaped[3][black]{%
  \mathpalette\@mathShaped{{#1}{#2}{3}}%
}
\newcommand\@mathShaped[3]{%
  \@mathShaped@b{#1}{#2}#3%
}
\newcommand\@mathShaped@b[4]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(math.base)] \node[draw,color=#2,shape=#3,inner sep=1pt] (math) {$\m@th#1#4$};%
}`
so I could let the shape be another optional argument, but my ability to generalize failed me again:     The call `$\mathShaped[red]{ellipse}{55}$` says I have an extra `}`.    Could you extend your answer to this case, please?

Comment: @skillmon : what do you mean with "\node[draw,color=#1,#2,inner sep=1pt] (math) {$\m@th#3#4$};", how to writre \mathcircled with for parameters? I wonder #3 and #4 meanings.

Comment: @pzorba75 `#3` is given by `\mathpalette` and is one of `\displaystyle`, `\textstyle`, `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle`. `#4` is the mandatory argument of `\mathcircled`. `#1` is the colour and `#2` is the shape (`circle` by default).