# How do I draw an ellipse around a term in an equation?

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, amsmath, circles

I have seen how to draw a circle around a term in an equation ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249688/how-do-i-draw-a-circle-around-a-term-in-an-align-equation)).
With the following code:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mathcircled[1]{%
  \mathpalette\@mathcircled{#1}%
}
\newcommand\@mathcircled[2]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(math.base)] \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt, blue] (math) {$\m@th#1#2$};%
}
\makeatother

Needed assumptions on F, since we know $\lambda_1^*$ must lie within $0,1$ \\
$\frac{b- \frac{F}{[\alpha(1-\gamma) - \gamma]}}{b-a} \leq 1 \iff b- \frac{F}{[\alpha(1-\gamma) - \gamma]} \leq b-a \iff \mathcircled{F \geq a \cdot [\alpha(1-\gamma) - \gamma]}$
```

I get this:
[image: aesthetically not satisfactory]

However, the result is aesthetically not satisfactory, since the term is quite long.
I would like the **circle/ellipse to rather adapt to the length of the term** (just like the `\boxed{}` command of `amsmath` does for instance). E.g something like the following for my example in particular: [image: Wanted result]

Comment: Use `ellipse` instead of `circle`? You need to `\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}`

Comment: Tikz also supports ellipse.  You might find https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399116/ideal-shape-of-elliptical-nodes useful.

Comment: Also look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/570856/how-can-i-highlight-part-of-an-equation-with-tikz-but-without-extra-space-around (search for "tikz latex highlight formula" in google  and you'll have plenty of them).

Comment: BTW, Welcome! Next time, please post [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to simplify the task of the answerer...

Comment: Do you want the ellipse to affect the spacing around the term, and if not should the ellipse be _behind_ the text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `circledsteps` package (based on `TiKZ`)  defines some rectangle with rounded smal sides for long terms.

However, if you really want an ellipse, `pstricks` defines a `\psovalbox`for that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circledsteps}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}

Needed assumptions on F, since we know $\lambda_1^*$ must lie within $0,1$
\[ \frac{b- \frac{F}{[\alpha(1-\gamma) - \gamma]}}{b-a} \leq 1 \iff b- \frac{F}{[\alpha(1-\gamma) - \gamma]} \leq b-a \iff \Circled[inner color=blue, outer color=blue]{F \geq a \cdot [\rule[-1.5ex]{0pt}{4ex}\alpha(1-\gamma) - \gamma]\:} \]

\[ \frac{b- \frac{F}{[\alpha(1-\gamma) - \gamma]}}{b-a} \leq 1 \iff b- \frac{F}{[\alpha(1-\gamma) - \gamma]} \leq b-a \iff \psovalbox[linecolor=blue, linewidth=0.5pt]{\color{blue} F \geq a \cdot [\rule[-1.5ex]{0pt}{4ex}\alpha(1-\gamma) - \gamma]} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Based on the solution you provide, why don't you use the `shape` library to draw an ellipse instead of a circle?

[image: ellipse around part of equation]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\mathcircled[1]{%
  \mathpalette\@mathcircled{#1}%
}
\newcommand\@mathcircled[2]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(math.base)] \node[draw,ellipse,inner sep=1pt] (math) {$\m@th#1#2$};%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\[
  L(q+\varepsilon) = \mathcircled{L(q) + \varepsilon \frac{dL}{d\varepsilon}} + \cdots
\]

\end{document}
```